# track to constraint rotation values

Tags: constraints

New Blender user here. (please be gentle)

I'm using a "track to" constraint to point an empty at another empty. Works exactely as expected, however the rotation values of the constrained empty don't change as it rotates to point at the target.
How do I access the resulting rotation values for the constrained object?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's available. Constraints are override any transform. While you use them, it doesn't count, because they will control the object anyway. If you want to save keyframes or an animation what made by the constraints you can add "Visual" keyframes (they are in the keyframe menu). Or you can bake the animation (Object>>Animation>>Bake Action).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried baking the driven rotations to an action and the curves have no values.
Excuse the complete noob question, but where would I find the keyframe menu?

Comment: Never mind... found it. In the preferences

Comment: You can "apply visual transform" to see the rotation values at any particular frame (although this may affect the way the track-to behaves; if you want, you can apply them on a duplicate.)  Baking will create keyframes only when you set it to bake visual transforms.  If you use a driver from the transform channels of the constrained empty, that's another way to get the transform of the empty.  Well, "a transform" not "the transform" because more than one set of values maps to the singular orientation.